# ¿como puede saber los dias que hay entre dos fechas de tipo timestamp? java 11

Tags: java

Hola he probrado de muchisimas formas y no puedo encontrar una que me devuelva el valor en dias, de dos fechas de tipo timestamp.
Solo necesito saber la fecha para que al restarlas, si me de menores a 30 dias realizar determinada cosa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es uno de los metodos que use, pero no me da los dias correctos

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El código va como texto en las preguntas. No es claro el tipo de dato involucrado en esas variables, así que tampoco es evidente decir si puedes usar `Duration.between(date1, date2).toDays();` o no... tampoco sabemos qué versión de Java usas. Puedes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Evita colocar imagenes de tu código, en su lugar puedes colocar el código como tal!

Comment: Dos cosas. La primera, por favor, coloca el código a texto, NO en imágenes. La segunda es ¿Cuál es el tipo de dato de que devuelve `getClosingDate`? ¿Es de tipo `Date`? ¿`LocalDateTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar, por alguna razon, al crear un objeto timestamp(new Date.get()) si mal no recuerdo eso hice o algo similar, como fecha actual me daba la de un dia menos que la que tenia en la computadora. Lo corregi agregandole 1 dia en milisegundos.

Comment: No olvides hacer lo que te mencionaron en los comentarios de la pregunta. Subir código como imagen [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.